# Autohotkey: WinMenuSelectItem not working on Figma

Tags: autohotkey

Hope someone can help me with this.
I am trying to use Autohotkey to automate some menu navigation within figma.
Point is that the "WinMenuSelectItem" function somehow doesn't work.

While searching for this, i found a script to detect any clicked menu item, and tell its position.
Turns out that none of the menu items, were detected.

it made me suspect that probably Figma's Windows app is just a disguised web browser, so i have to approach this differently.

A solution could be to create my shortcuts through mouse position, but i once i switch screens, all the positioning will be messed.

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Edit: As request, im going to paste the code i have right now.
But is almost of no use, as now i am using mouse movement to click on menu items, and this solution is both slow (on performing time) and as soon as i change screen resolution, those coordinates render useless.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

^!+f1:: ; Go to main component
SendEvent {Click 28 63}
sleep, 100 ;
SendEvent {Click 93 228}
sleep, 400 ;
SendEvent {Click 291 464}
sleep, 100 ;
SendEvent {Click 550, 463}

CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseMove, (A_ScreenWidth // 2), (A_ScreenHeight // 2)
return

^!+f2:: ; Plugin Papa component
SendEvent {Click 28 63}
sleep, 100 ;
SendEvent {Click 93 338}
sleep, 400 ;
SendEvent {Click 296 535}
sleep, 100 ;

CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseMove, (A_ScreenWidth // 2), (A_ScreenHeight // 2)
return


^!+f3:: ; Copy Prototype link
SendEvent {Click 2374 69}
sleep, 400 ;
SendEvent {Click 1109 506}
return
```

Comment: Could you please share the code you tried to use?

Comment: Could you use [ImageSearch](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm) and small images of the elements that you need to click?